# Repeat match pattern and replace

Tags: vim

I'd like to repeat a search and replace as below:

Example:

```
set_path 1 -start -from [get_obj { A_1[0] B_2[1] .... Z_n[100] }]
```

replace to

```
set_path 1 -start -from [get_obj {xyz/A_1[0] xyz/B_2[1]  .... xyz/Z_n[100]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and why aren't you satisfied with it?! Stack Overflow doesn't absolve you from thinking :-)

Comment: I tried to match using "/\({\w\+\)\(\%(\w\+\W\+\)\{2,}\)" but this was  not giving desired result.

Answer (score 2):

hit Esc, and type:

```
:%s/array/xyz\/array/g
```

Comment: Thanks Diego. My search requirement is even trickier. I'd like to search and replace as below:
set_path 1 -start -from [get_obj { A_1[0] B_2[1] .... Z_n[100] }] replace to set_path 1 -start -from [get_obj {xyz/A_1[0] xyz/B_2[1] .... xyz/Z_n[100]

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/ \(\u\)/ xyz\/\1/g
```

\1 means the content matched in the first brackets.
It means replace every space and a uppercase letter to xyz and the uppercase letter.

Comment: Hi Zyan, Thanks for your reply. I'll try you suggestion and update you. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I just forget add "/" for replacement. And now it works.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work with variably named array names, you could do something like this:

```
s:\v([^[ {]+\[[0-9]+\]):xyz/\1:g
```

- `\v` turns on "very magic" regular expressions, see `:help /magic`.
- `[^[ {]+` ensures the only strings **not** starting with a bracket, space or curly brace are matched.
- `\[[0-9]+\]` ensures that it "looks" like an array reference.

Comment: Hi Thor, Thanks for your reply. This works for me. Thanks for the exaplanation.