# vim: Matching words multiple times and replace

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Repeat match pattern and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816063/repeat-match-pattern-and-replace)

How to match whole word with a specific pattern multiple times and replace in multiple lines?

Example:

```
set_path 1 -start -from [get_obj { A_1[0] B_2[1] .... Z_n[100] }]
```

replace to

```
set_path 1 -start -from [get_obj {xyz/A_1[0] xyz/B_2[1]  .... xyz/Z_n[100] }]
```

Comment: Hi Thor, There is a difference in the question compared to before.

Comment: No significant difference. Modify your earlier question if you are not happy with the answers.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you can use `:s@\<\ze[A-Z]_@xyz/@g`

detail:

- `:s` is substitution command, `@` is pattern and replacement delimiter
- `\<` matches at beginning of word
- `\ze` has the same effect as putting the rest of the pattern as a lookahead positive assertion
- `@g` enables multiple substitutions on the same line.

If you need this on multiple lines, just prefix `s` with a range: `:20,30s` or `:%s`, or hit `:` when your lines are highlighted in a visual selection, the command line will start with `:'<,'>`, add the s.

Comment: Thanks Benoit. I'll try your suggestion.